# Compare a class with element in array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, class

I'm trying to compare an element of class `$('.prova');` with an elements in an array `array=[.prova,.prova2]` and if they are equal the element `$('.prova')` they will be showed.

Please help me

```
$('.prova').filter(array.join()).show();
        $('.prova').filter(classes.join()).hide();
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @fauxserious i edited the code

Comment: Please clarify your question; it's quite unclear

Comment: It seems you are looking in your document for elements of a particular class. If you find the element, you want to show it. Is that correct?

Comment: yes @fauxserious show that element and hide the others....i'm sorry but i can't explain clearly, i'm not so good in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will find all divs on a page, and check the class includes the word "prova" before show/hiding them

```
function showProva(){
    $('div').each(function(){
         $(this).toggle($(this).prop('class').indexOf('prova') >= 0);
    })
}
```

You can call this on load or an event listener.

Comment: how i could do if i don't know the exact name of the element in array?